# How to make a C Program for Game of Life using text file

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I was asked to:

Create an ANSI C program that will read a textﬁle containing a 25 x 25 matrix of the character ‘x’ or the blank space.

```
Display the initial generation using the function printf.

Calculate the next generation using the rules mentioned above and save it in another textﬁle.

The filenames of the input and output textﬁles should be speciﬁed as command-line parameters.
```

all i have so far is a code that asks for the text file then my code prints it. i lack the codes applying the rules of Conway's Game of Life. I don't know where to put it. and what codes to use. :( please help me.

here`s what i have now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 80
#define N 25

void display(char [][N+1], size_t);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  char in[MAX_LINE_LEN];
  char grid[N][N+1] = { { '\0' } };
  size_t i = 0;

  printf("Enter filename: ");
  fgets(in, MAX_LINE_LEN, stdin);
  *(strchr(in, '\n')) = '\0';
  if ((fp = fopen(in, "r")) != NULL) {
    while ((i < N) && (fgets(in, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL)) {
      *(strchr(in, '\n')) = '\0';
      /* should verify only 'x' and space in string before storing */
      strncpy(grid[i++], in, N);
    }
    /* pad each row with spaces, if necessary, for NxN array */
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      while (strlen(grid[i]) < N) {
        strcat(grid[i], " ");
      }
    }
    /* For all generations ...
            compute next generation */
            display(grid, N);
    /* End for all generations */
  } else {
    printf("%s not found.\n", in);
    getch();
  }
  getch();
}

void display(char a[][N+1], size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; puts(a[i++]));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Game of Life using C Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589328/how-to-make-a-game-of-life-using-c-language)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1823/10396

Answer (score 3):

```
*(strchr(in, '\n')) = '\0';
```

Bad juju.  If `strchr` returns NULL, this will segfault.  I know your data will always have a newline, but it's a bad habit to get into.  *Always* assign the result of `strchr` to a variable and perform a NULL check first:

```
char *tmp = strchr(in, '\n');
if (tmp)
  *tmp = 0;
```

Frankly, I think treating your grid as an array of strings will cause more grief than it will solve.  Treat it like you would a 2d array of any other type.  Dealing with the newlines at the end of each line in the input file will be a pain no matter what you do.

As far as how to structure your code, think about the problem at a high level:

1. You need to **load** a file as your starting grid;
2. You need to **calculate** the grid for the next generation, for some number of generations;
3. You need to **display** each grid;
4. You need to **write** each grid to a file.

You've already split the display code out into its own function; you just need to do the same for the load, calculate, and write functions (you *could* leave the file loading code in `main`, but it would make the code cleaner if you put it in its own function).

```
void load(const char *filename, char (*grid)[N], size_t rows) {...}
void calc(char (*grid)[N], size_t rows) {...}
void save(const char *filename, char (*grid)[N], size_t rows) {...}
```

So each time through in `main`, you'll just call `calc` on the grid before calling `display`, then you'll call `save` to write the new grid to a file.

As for *how* to calculate the next grid, well, that's part of your assignment, and I don't want to give it *all* away.